# probability of collision with randomly generated ID

Tags: probability

### Reworded: If 10,000 events occur each second, and each event needs a unique ID, how many random bits does each ID require to insure collisions are minimized?

$10,000$ events could occur near the same time, so the time stamp is not sufficient for a unique ID.  I want to add a number of random bits (but not too many) to make collisions unlikely.  This sounds like the birthday paradox problem.

If I add $12$-bits of randomness, that too low because $10,000$ events into $4096$ boxes must have some duplicates.

If I add $18$-bits of randomness, $$p()=1-\left(\frac{262143}{262144}\right)^{(10000(10000-1))/2)} = 100 \%$$

If I add $24$-bits of randomness, $$p()=1-\left(\frac{16777215}{16777216}\right)^{10000(10000-1))/2} = 94.9 \%$$

Did I do this right? My math sense expects this to be more than enough, since each event has $1677$ possible places to go without collision.

At $32$ bits, there is a $1.1\%$ chance, and at $36$ bits the probability of a collision is $727$ parts per million.

I am starting to understand why the standard UUID generators use $128$ bits.

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I don't follow, what is the question here? It's hard to understand what you're aiming to find.

Comment: I think the Question is what is the probability of a collision in randomly assigning 10,000 values of some specified number of bits.  Confusion arises from how wrongly the calculation is being done.

Comment: I have to temper my remark about the calculation being done wrongly, as the results agree with my calculations (below).  However even with the benefit of redoing these, I fail to understand the method used here.  It seems the exponent reflects doing something with the possibility of each *pair* of 10,000 items not colliding, but these are not independent events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed this is the [birthday paradox/problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for a very long calendar.  The calculations sketched are not exact ones (see below), but they are [good approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations) for such large numbers.  I've added an example at bottom to show the difference appearing with smaller values.

Suppose there are $N$ boxes (where in the suggested application, $N=2^k$ for simplicity).  We would compute the chance that *no* collision occurs in putting $m=10000$ items in those boxes randomly, and subtract from $1$ to get the probability *some* (at least one) collision occurs.

Assuming each of the ten-thousand items is assigned a box with uniform and independent probabilities, we can think of the universe of outcomes as $N^{10000}$ points.  To count the outcomes which have no more than one item in any box, we need to multiply the combinations of $N$ things taken $10000$ at a time by the number of permutations of those $10000$ distinct boxes:

$$ \text{Pr}(\text{no collision}) = \frac{\binom{N}{10000} 10000!}{N^{10000}} $$

Of course we are dealing with some large numbers here, so either a symbolic math program or an approximation is called for.

Wolfram Alpha says the probability of no collision for $N=2^{18}$ is vanishingly small, about $10^{-84}$.  For $N=2^{24}$ the value is $0.0507661...$, which agrees with the value shown in the Question.

Wolfram Alpha also agrees [with the value for 32 bits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom%282%5E32%2C10000%29*10000%21%2F%282%5E320000%29) at $0.988427...$ chance of no collision.

**Added:**  It appears the idea of the calculations in the Question is to treat all possible $\binom{10000}{2}$ pairs of entries as if they had an independent chance of colliding.  A small calculation will show this is not true, although the agreement for 10000 items is striking.

Suppose eight boxes in which we place four items.  Now the method in the Question treats this as six independent pairs of items, each with a $7/8$ths chance of not colliding.  For  all six pairs *not* to collide has then probability:

$$ \left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^6 \approx 0.448795319 $$

But the method above computes the chance of no collision when placing four items at random in the eight boxes at:

$$ \frac{\binom{8}{4} 4!}{8^4} = \frac{105}{256} = 0.41015625 $$

To do the calculation in the way typical of "birthday problem" presentations, consider that the first choice can be made in any of eight out of eight ways without a collision, the second choice made in seven out of eight ways (to avoid colliding with the first choice), and so on:

$$ \frac{8}{8} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{6}{8} \cdot \frac{5}{8} = \frac{105}{256} $$

The difference between "independent pair collisions" and the birthday problem is explained by the probabilities of the pairs colliding *not* being independent.  For example, if items $A$ and $B$ do not collide, and items $A$ and $C$ do not collide, then the chance of $B$ and $C$ not colliding is no longer $\frac{N-1}{N}$ but rather $\frac{N-2}{N-1}$ since both $B$ and $C$ are known to avoid $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the review.  When I first started looking at the problem, it sounded a lot like the chances of two people in a group having the same birthday.  That is where my equation came from.

Comment: It is the birthday problem with a very long calendar.  I'll add to my Answer to make this clear.